# What does _ah mean in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does the `_ah` mean anything in Google App Engine?

I'm not looking to find out what it's used for or where is it located and how it works. As some answers below mentioned it's a reserved path for admin stuff.

But the letters, **a** and **h** together, is it an abbreviation or something?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It comes from apphosting, the underscore is to make it more difficult to collide with some user provided URL.

Edit: I worked at Google, apphosting was the first name they selected for AppEngine, and this name still remains in some parts of the internal configuration.

Comment: @JoaquinCuencaAbela Do you have any ideas for that [similar question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/15416/17379)?

Answer (score 9):

`/_ah/` is a [reserved URL path](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Reserved_URLs) used by App Engine for **features** (mail, warmup, login, etc.) or **administrative** purposes.
Script handler and static file handler paths will never match this path.

Comment: That's right, but it doesn't answer my question. Posted an update for clarification.

Comment: why isn't it _fa or _af then?

Comment: I think they will match. At least the login required script.

Comment: The "reserved URL path" link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's short for 'admin handler', but that's just a guess really.