# Resident Backend Google App Engine "/_ah/background" (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Can someone help me understand what "/_ah/background" is in terms of google app engine (Python).  I have a resident backend running, and I am seeing requests being made to that endpoint.  They appear to be generated by something outside my code.  They also appear to be being handled by my /_ah/start handler.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `/_ah/background` requests aren't actually HTTP requests, they're [background threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Background_threads). App Engine uses `/_ah/background` as a placeholder wherever it needs to group something by request, e.g. log messages. This matches what I see in my backends that use background threads.

(I could swear I read this in the docs somewhere recently, but I haven't found where yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Any URL that starts with "/_ah/" is a reserved AppEngine URL.  These are used for internal AppEngine tasks, you really shouldn't need to worry about them.

[What does _ah mean in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408042/what-does-ah-mean-in-google-app-engine)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=it-IT#Reserved_URLs

Comment: To be clear, my question is why is google calling /_ah/background and why is it hitting my start handler.  I am not attempting to make calls to these *reserved* handlers, however you can and should worry about them when creating backend instances in app engine.  Please see this:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Startup

Comment: depending on the language/framework you use, this unuseful error gets your logs quite dirty