# What is `/_ah/background` with Google Flex VM

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-managed-vm

Started using [Google Flex Vms](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) recently and in the logs there are multiple requests to `/_ah/background` that last ~1 hour each time. The only reference to these I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450534/resident-backend-google-app-engine-ah-background-python) question which mentions they have to do with [background threads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Background_threads) but I don't believe that's the case here as:

- nowhere do we use background threads
- that API is deprecated and I'm not even sure we can use it
- we do use processes but they're short-lived (nowhere near an hour) and don't print any log messages

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/_ah/background` is used in flex for AE API calls that are called outside of an incoming request processing context (like threads, async-io, ...).

Even if you don't do that directly log flushing is still done asynchronously (not part of an income request processing).

This is an implementation details and there is a plan to hide it but still
find a way to show (in log, trace,...) information about these API calls.

Comment: Any update on this? It's particularly annoying because it makes all Stackdriver latency graphs and alerts unuseable

Comment: We hear you.  We're actively working on fixing this right now.  We don't have an eta quite yet, but it will be in our next big release.

Comment: @JustinBeckwith Has this been resolved? We are noticing the same thing in our Node.js application.

Comment: This has been fixed.  If you are using `env:flex` you shouldn't see these requests.

Comment: Which part was fixed @JustinBeckwith: StackDriver graphs/alerts? The logs? The actual use of `/_ah/background`? I have some push-tasks with a `Referer` header of `oldversion.myapp.appspot.com/_ah/background` that I'm trying to debug execution issues with, and I'm not sure exactly where they came from. (I'm using `env:flex`, with 3 days old tasks)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I thought sharing this picture will provide little insight on the frequency, (possible performance) impact this /_ah/background creates..

is there any workaround to clear this ?

[image]