# Google App Engine - nodejs application goes down over night

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am using google app engine to host a single instance nodejs application. The application works fine and my scripts are showing no errors in the logs. The application is currently just in testing and is not getting used over night, however often I come to work the next day and the server is just returning internal server errors. No errors are shown in my application log other then the 502 errors which i get when trying to access the next day. I see like 100s of calls for /_ah/_background/ overnight some appear to have timed out. At this point I must restart my instance for the app to continue to function.

I am completely stumped.. Because my app using web-sockets I must use manual scaling and a single instance. Would appreciate any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a gues that you have a deferred task stuck running. Tasks that run in the taskqueue api are set by default to continuously retry. You can visit the taskqueue api [TaskQueue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/)

To get the tasks to stop running right now visit the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
select your project. Then select App Engine. Then select Task queues. Click on the task that is running (probably default). There should be a option to Pause the queue. This should prevent the 500 errors from occurring but will not fix the reason the task is failing.

Comment: thanks. Nothing in my task queue though. Also I dont actually get any errors so that is the confusing part. All I see is those  /_ah/_background/ calls in the logs overnight. When i test at work the instance seems to stay up all day without a hitch.

Comment: If its not task queue, then maybe a backend module/ thread is running? '/_ah/' is a reserved route in app engine, for internal app engine use.

Comment: [relevant link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450534/resident-backend-google-app-engine-ah-background-python)

Comment: Yeah there isn't anything I have added outside my main application. The server is getting no hits at these times and the only thing I see in the logs is /_ah/ calls. I am using websockets if that matters nothing is connected over night though.